# Ruby on Rails best practices -- create a Pages controller for shared layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the standard way to structure a Rails app's semi-static web pages?

I come from a LAMP background and traditionally I'd have pages such as this:

```
about.php
index.php
common/
    header.php
    footer.php
    scripts.php
    (etc)
sign-up.php
scripts/
    jQuery.js
    etc
styles/
    main.css
(etc)
```

Inside those files, there would be a php include for the header, footer, etc.

Should I generate a controller called Pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question straight: don't create a Controller for shared layout ... But follow the advice below:

1.`about.php, index.php, sign-up.php`:

`about` and `index` actions could be gathered in a controller, generally I name it `Static`.

So logically, views would be in `/app/views/static/`

For `sign_up` it would depend on your choice: whether or not you want it to stick to your `User` model. Generally, it goes to some `Registration` controller.

2.`common/ header.php, footer.php, scripts.php`would become:

`layouts/_header.html.erb, _footer.html.erb, _scripts.html.erb` + you should create a layout including these partials.

3.`scripts/jQuery.js` and `styles/main.css` will go to `/public/javascripts`and `/public/stylesheets` (at least for Rails 3.0.x)

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for are `Layouts`.  Essentially, you define a layout in `/app/views/layouts` (the default being `application.html.erb`), which is a "wrapper" for all of your page content.  This layout can include any other files you might want, and can be dynamically modified by each individual view.  You can read the official tutorial [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages) R. Bates' railscast demonstrate all what you need!